# API Call is going after providing conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make API call and sending storeId and consultuntId to backend, its working fine.
This is the code:-

```
const urlParams = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams;
const live_shopping_events_parameter = Object.fromEntries(urlParams);
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: '/aos/lscommission',
data: {
storeId: live_shopping_events_parameter.r,
consultuntId: live_shopping_events_parameter.z,
},
success: function (){
},
error: function(error) {
},
});
```

But I need to check two condition

1. the url fields exist and are valid
2. non-empty numeric for storeId and consultantId

This is the Example URL - https://www.example.com/live-shopping-events?r=MDQyMDE%3d&z=56
Where r is is the storeId and z is the consultuntId.

This is my code to check non-empty numeric for storeId and consultantId

```
const urlParams = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams;
const live_shopping_events_parameter = Object.fromEntries(urlParams);
if(live_shopping_events_parameter !== 'undefined' || live_shopping_events_parameter !== null ) {
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: '/aos/lscommission',
data: {
storeId: live_shopping_events_parameter.r,
consultuntId: live_shopping_events_parameter.z,
},
success: function (){
},
error: function(error) {
},
});
}else{
   console.log("error");
}
```

for this code if I remove parameters (https://www.example.com/live-shopping-events), then still it is making API call.
How to solve this issue.

Comment: `live_shopping_events_parameter` will never be null or undefined.  It might be empty, which you are not checking for.

Comment: check for specific object properties, like `if (live_shopping_events_parameter.r !== 'undefined' ` and so on

Comment: Why are you not actually validating the parameters are there and that they contain the data you expect?

Comment: You've also misspelled "consultant" multiple times which might break your request.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to condition in the whole object returning from Object.entries which will always return an object. That is why your condition is becoming true always. You should try to factor in the property you are trying to find, like this:

```
if (live_shopping_events_parameter.r !== undefined || live_shopping_events_parameter.z !== undefined) {
  /* You code here */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOULTION EXPLAINATION:**

Thats because irrespective if there are url params or not the Object.fromEntries(urlParams) will return an object. If you want to check if params exist you need to check individually like `live_shopping_events_parameter.r`, this will return true is param exists and false if param is absent and make API call only when it is true.

**SOULTION CODE:**

```
const urlParams = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams;
const live_shopping_events_parameter = Object.fromEntries(urlParams);

if(live_shopping_events_parameter.r && live_shopping_events_parameter.z) {
    //Params exist
    //Make API call here..
    console.log('Calling API')
}else{
   // No params found
    console.log('Params missing')
}
```